# assistance with getting form input into js variable; but have them both be elements in an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Hello: here is what I am trying to do.  I think it is doable but just not quite sure exactly how.  What I want is multiple instances of a form input (generated by a loop) and then be able to pull the form input into a js variable (probably also an element of an array to keep them all seperate...

So I have been messing around with this a good deal and so far no luck...

pretty high up in my doc i create my js arrays for later use (not using all of them):

```
<script>
var ajax_functions = new Array();
var image_orders = new Array();

var new_order4 = new Array();
var gtest84 = new Array();
var gtest85 = new Array();
</script>
```

here is the input

```
gtest84:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="gtest55" name="baker84[<?php echo $image_id; ?>]"><br/>
```

finally here is my js code that attempts to gather the input into js array element...

```
gtest84[input_img_id] = document.getElementsByName(baker84[input_img_id]);
gtest85[input_img_id] = gtest84[input_img_id].value;
```

1. A couple of notes:  i left of the  tags off second js code to save room
2. also the php variable of $image_id is established and set and working well...
3. finally the js variable "input_image_id" is set by an input to the js function and I know that is working (it is the same value as the php variable from #2)

Like I said - i am not able to pull it and push into my js array element like i am trying to do...  So I am hoping someone can help with this...

All the best,  Gerard

Comment: Having a hard time trying to understand what you're trying to accomplish. JavaScript arrays have a push method that allows you to put things into them. As it stands, by using [ ] syntax, you're simply assigning properties to your array objects (since they're just special objects).

Comment: thanks for commenting - I will try and explain further:  the page is to edit "the order" on how some images are displayed somewhere else...so lets say there are 5 images; so we have a modal with a form to change the order for each image...so if there are 5 images then there will be 5 "instances of the form" (in 5 different modals)...so far all this is working; i have the 5 modals and the 5 forms within them; i even have 5 js functions to go with each modal...but since it is the same form from modal to modal - and the js function is the repeated as well; ...

Comment: my way of being able to have each form input be seperate from the other 5 is have it be part of an array; and the js variable for it to be gathered in the same way...does this help explain?  thanks,  G

Comment: I think what would be more helpful is what is the end result you're trying to achieve. What would the data look like after you were done putting things in arrays?

Comment: the end result is taking the value of the input and doing an ajax call and passing the value...I have found that if the multiple form instances have the same name and the multiple js functions have the same var name for it to be stored in to send to ajax; then once i fill out form once on one image; any future filling out of the forms - the value passed through  ajax does not change...so i am trying to ensure that the value passed to ajax is different depending on which of the 5 form instances are filled  out

Comment: I am pretty sure the form input has to be named discreetly from the other form inputs on the other instacnces of the form; i am not so sure that the js vars have to be an array - but it seems like that would be needed as well

Comment: I must not be making myself clear enough. What would the data you're putting in the arrays actually look like once you're done?

Comment: well to be honest i want to pass a number from a radio input...but i was having problems and so i switched to a text input which can be a string or a number...does that answer you?